# MYSQL Query Where Clause unexpected results

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE:** this `query` is for *forgot password*. *emailAdd* and *accountNumber* serve as username, user either enter `accountNumber` or `emailAdd`.

I am confused why my `select` `query` returns the `row` that are not even equal to my `where` `clause`.

**sample table**

```
accountNumber  |  email
    0          |  a@g.c
    100        |  b@g.c
```

**query**

```
SELECT accountNumber , email FROM tblsample WHERE accountNumber ='c@g.c' OR email='c@g.c'
```

**unexpected output**

```
accountNumber | email
     0        | a@g.c
```

**expected output**

```
accountNumber  | email
```

it should not return any `row` because as you can see in `where` `clause` **c@g.c is not equal to 0**

**additional info**

`column accountNumber` is `int`

`column email` is `varchar`

Comment: why would you want to test the email address against the accountNumber column? Not clear why you'd even attempt this. And clearly you can't compare a string to an int. they are different datatypes.

Comment: @ADyson, sorry for not clearing it. `accountNumber` column is act as like `emailAdd` aka username. That query is for *forgot password*, basically, those two are one of the options for *signing in* and also for *forgot password*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any issue in the query, you have datatype for accountNumber as int and for email as varchar. When you pass string for int column, it wont be able to cast the the string to int as there is not any integer value in the string at initial points so it will return 0. That 0 value is matched with the first record in the database so it returned the first row. You should type case the integer column to character to compare with the string value.

For Example:

```
SELECT accountNumber , email FROM  tblsample WHERE cast(accountNumber as char(11)) ="c@g.c" OR email="c@g.c";
```

This will not return any rows because it do not match the condition. Please let me know if you have any more confusions.

Comment: upon trying it out, it works and I am getting expected results.